# Using the C++ standard library in a Windows User Mode Driver

Tags: c++, windows, driver, umdf

I recently got tasked with writing Windows user mode drivers for our devices and have a good grasp of the WDF and UMDF basics, after reading up on the topic and studying the template projects in Visual Studio 2017.

I'm determined to use as much modern C++ as possible, and if that can include the standard library too, then I'll be much happier than if I need to make my own corresponding functionalities.

Are there any best practices around using modern C++ in Windows user mode drivers in general, and using modern C++ *standard library* features in specific?

What are the pitfalls I need to look out for, that can be circumvented?

Should I avoid it completely? If so, on what grounds?

Comment: How is this question stated too broadly? (votes to close for that reason...)

Comment: You are practically writing a user mode application. The name says it all, no reason to overthink. Just do what you would do in a "normal" application.